# How can I using Python to query mongodb where time key is the last five minutes?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I use fluent and mongodb to storage my apache access log.

The log format output in python like this:

```
>>> collection.find_one({"host":"192.168.1.57"})

{u'_id': ObjectId('50dd5367febb00575f000088'),
u'agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0',
u'code': 200,
u'host': u'192.168.1.57',
u'method': u'GET',
u'path': u'/',
u'referer': None,
u'size': 8675,
u'time': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28, 8, 8, 7),
u'user': None}
```

So, how can I query the log where access time is the last five minutes?

Comment: what have you tried? Why don't you perform a range search on the time field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer to your problem by search the fine MongoDB documentation for the $gt operator or checking for range searches:

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/